# Ensuring continuity of random processes sample path

Tags: probability, probability-theory, continuity, random-variables

I have been exploring probability and random variables a little more in depth recently as I only got a very rudimentary education on probability theory in my undergrad, and I am curious how one would ensure continuity for a continuous random process. For a function $f: t \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be continuous at a point $t_0$, we must have:

$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow t_0} f(t) = f(t_0) $$

Right? But when dealing with the sample path of a continuous random process, how can one ensure that this will occur as one approaches $t_0$? Couldn't the random variable theoretically fluctuate indefinitely as one approaches $t_0$ thereby making the limit undefined? If that is true, then how is this addressed to produce a mathematically sound theory of continuous random processes?

Comment: The analysis is really careful and is not easy to be explained as you only got a very rudimentary education on probability theory (and probably not familiar with measure theory). One typical example is to prove the existence of Wiener processes and you can google it first. If you still want to know and need more referrences, I will write an answer.

Comment: Would you mind writing an answer? I would be interested to know and see if I can understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is really careful and not easy to be explained as you only got a very rudimentary education on probability theory. One typical example is to prove the existence of Wiener processes.

For a direct and intuitive construction, see an excellent self-contained text by Geoffrey Grimmett, *Probability and random processes*. The construction starts from the bottom of P522. We first prove that the Wiener processes have almost surely continuous sample paths on the set of dyadic rationals. Moreover, we can extend the Wiener processes by continuity from the dyadic rationals to the entire set of $[0,1]$ and of course further into the set of $[0, \infty)$.

For a more concise and rigorous construction, see a book by a well-known author Lawrence C. Evans, *An Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations*. It also contains some historical developments of Brownian motions in Chapter 3. Here we express the white noise as a formal expansion in terms of an orthonormal basis in $L^2(0,1)$. The integration of such a expansion in time will show that this series converges and further prove the existence of a Weiner process.

Also, there is a complete and old-fashioned book by Bernt Øksendal, *Stochastic Differential Equations: An Introduction with Applications*. This is for you if you are interested in further topics.

This post will end with a direct answer, which is also an important result, but it is useless to you without further context.

> **Kolmogorov's Continuity Theorem**
>
> Suppose that a stochastic process $X = \{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ satisfies the following condition: For all $T >0$, there exist positive constants $\alpha, \beta, D$ such that
> $$
> \mathbb{E}[|X_t-X_s|^\alpha] \leq D \cdot |t-s|^{1+\beta}
> $$
> for $0 \leq s,t \leq T$. Then there exists a continuous version of $X$.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer! Is either book you mentioned free online? Or do you have to buy them?

Comment: Yes, they are all free online. That's also why I recommended them.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!